# Php session is not shared across subdomains

Tags: php, session, subdomain

I have multiple subdomains, I'm sharing a session across them, but it's only showing in couple of the subdomains, in the subdomains where the session is not showing, I found that there is a different session with a different id.

session.cookie_domain is set to ".my_domain_name" and is start the session at the beginning of the code

what is causing this behavior?

Comment: If you are setting the exact same session cookie parameters for all of them, then maybe you have 3rd-party cookies blocked in your browser for _some_ of them?

Comment: @CBroe That's a possibility, I'm still looking into it and going through all the possible solutions